# how to save a string token , save its content to an array, then use those contents for further comparison

Tags: c, string, strtok, strdup

/*I am unsure if my code for saving the tokens in an array is accurate. 
This is so because been whenever I run my program, the code to compare 
`token[0]` with my variable doesn't give an output nor perform assigned function.

Hence I am sure there is something inaccurate about my coding.*/

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    //variable declarations        
   const char *array[] = {"ax","bo","cf"};
   char delim[]=" \n";
   char* myline;
   size_t max = 500;
   char* token1;
   char* token2[max];
   int n = 0;


   while(1)    //loop always
   {      
      printf("Enter an argument\n");   //asks for an input


      getline (&myline, &max, stdin);     //read the input/line              

      //for loop -- splits up the line into tokens
      for(token1 = strtok(myline, " "); token1 != NULL; token1 = strtok(NULL, delim))
      {                  

         token2[n] = malloc(strlen(token1)+1);     //allocate some space/memory to token2[n]

         //save the token in an array by copying from token1 to token2
         strcpy(token2[n],token1);


         int m;

         for(m = 0; m<sizeof(array);m++)    //loop through the array elements for comparison
         { 
            //compare array at index m with token at index 0 --  compare only first token with a specific variable 

           if(strcmp(token2[0], array[m]) == 0)
           {
               printf("equal");
           }
         }
       }

   free(token2[n]);     //deallocate assigned memory
   }       
 return(0);
}
```

Comment: The only problem with your code is style and not checking `malloc`'s return value.

Comment: Where do you read the line?

Comment: line is read from stdin using getline

Comment: 1) `char delim[]="";` --> `char delim[]=" \n";` 2) `if(strcmp(token2[0], array[0]) == 0){` --> `if(strcmp(token2[n], array[0]) == 0){` and into loop ?

Comment: Why `while(i == 0)`? Why not simply `while (1)`.

Comment: Also why are you allocating `myline`? `getline()` will do this for you.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY my comparison is between the first token and the array

Comment: _the code to compare  token[n] with my variable_

Comment: @Atinuke So you want to compare the first token, `token2[0]` with each element of the array `array[i]`?

Comment: exactly @RoadRunner .... i made some changes to my code

Comment: `free(tokens[n]); `? I think this is a typo. You only have `token1` and `token2`. And `for(m = 0; m<strlen;m++) ` is not correct. you can do something like: `for(m = 0; m<sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); m++) `. There are better ways to do this, maybe you can use a macro instead?

Comment: I still need the comparison to work ...

Comment: @Atinuke Your comparison will never work because `getline()` adds a newline character at the end of buffer. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try vector of string like

vector < string > str = { "ax","bo","cf" };

Comment: This is `c++`. OP won't find this useful as question is tagged in `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Their seems to be a few issues in your current code:

- `for(m = 0; m<strlen;m++)` is not correct. `strlen()` is a `<string.h>` function used to obtain the length of a C string. Since you want `array[i]`, you need to include the size of `array` in the guard. To find the size of the array, you can use `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`. It would be good to include this in a macro:

  ```
  #define ARRAYSIZE(x) (sizeof x/sizeof x[0])
  ```

  Then your loop can be:

  ```
  size_t m;
  for(m = 0; m<ARRAYSIZE(array); m++)
  ```
- You need to check return of `malloc()`, as it can return `NULL` on failure to allocate spaces. Here is a way to check this:

  ```
  token2[n] = malloc(strlen(token1)+1);
  if (token2[n] == NULL) {
      /* handle error */
  ```
- It is possible to skip the `malloc()`/`strcpy()` step by simply using [`strdup`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup).
- `getline()` returns `-1` on failure to read a line, so its good to check this. It also adds a `\n` character at the end of the buffer, so you need to remove this. Otherwise, `strcmp` will never find equal strings, as you will be comparing `strcmp("string\n", "string")`. You need to find the `\n` character in your buffer, and replace it with a `\0` null-terminator.

  You can achieve this like:

  ```
  size_t slen = strlen(myline);
  if (slen > 0 && myline[slen-1] == '\n') {
      myline[slen-1] = '\0';
  }
  ```
- You also need to `free()` all of the `char*` pointers in `token2[]`.
- Since you are using the same delimeter for `strtok()`, its better to make this `const`. So `const char *delim = " \n";` instead.

Alot of the fixes I suggested in the comments, so I didn't post them here, as you seemed to have updated your code with those suggestions.

Comment: @Atinuke These issues should help you debug your code.